# rsync doesn't copy some files - failed to open /tmp files

Tags: macos, rsync

I am trying to copy everything from one disk partition to another, so I have used:

```
> time sudo rsync -aE --progress  /Volumes/Files/ /Volumes/xxxx\ archive
```

The copy takes almost 10 hours for about 557 GB. At the end I see:

```
sent 555851786605 bytes  received 17096882 bytes  15585618.69 bytes/sec
total size is 553799473828  speedup is 1.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
```

After trying several searches to find the errors in one and a half million lines, I find this:

```
Apple development/ethernal Folder/__MACOSX/
Apple development/ethernal Folder/__MACOSX/Ethernal 1.2/
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._.DS_Store.QTDkX5": No such file or directory
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._Read-me.rtf.TFnOeF": No such file or directory
Apple development/ethernal Folder/__MACOSX/Ethernal 1.2/Source/
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._.DS_Store.j5YUu5": No such file or directory
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._EthernalIcon.icns.JBXisF": No such file or directory
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._Read-me.rtf.GFp1z0": No such file or directory
Apple development/ethernal Folder/__MACOSX/Ethernal 1.2/Source/Doc/
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._.DS_Store.WbalMH": No such file or directory
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._Ethernet Type Codes.webloc.G2KRaL": No such file or directory
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._Ethernet- IEEE 802.3 Local Area Network (LAN) protocols Overview.webloc.Yerfpk": No such file or directory
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._IP Protocol. Description and Packet Format.webloc.xscjxl": No such file or directory
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._Internet Protocol (IP).webloc.KecBNl": No such file or directory
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._gethostbyaddr - Linux Command - Unix Command-1.webloc.Kh5hkS": No such file or directory
Apple development/ethernal Folder/__MACOSX/Ethernal 1.2/Source/Library/
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._.DS_Store.O7hunu": No such file or directory
Apple development/ethernal Folder/__MACOSX/Ethernal 1.2/Source/Library/MoreAuthSample/
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._.DS_Store.Sg5lY7": No such file or directory
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._MoreSetup.h.wQB79W": No such file or directory
Apple development/ethernal Folder/__MACOSX/Ethernal 1.2/Source/Library/MoreAuthSample/MoreCFQ/
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._MoreCFQ.c.ftZTAb": No such file or directory
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._MoreCFQ.h.kA3Dvb": No such file or directory
Apple development/ethernal Folder/__MACOSX/Ethernal 1.2/Source/Library/MoreAuthSample/MoreSecurity/
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._.DS_Store.79V4Rd": No such file or directory
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._MoreSecurity.c.rjTB8I": No such file or directory
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._MoreSecurity.h.6qJ5qq": No such file or directory
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._ReadMeAboutMoreAuthSample.html.zgJcn5": No such file or directory
Apple development/ethernal Folder/__MACOSX/Ethernal 1.2/Source/Library/MoreAuthSample/MoreSecurity/MoreSecurityTest/
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._.DS_Store.WvdnjK": No such file or directory
Apple development/ethernal Folder/__MACOSX/Ethernal 1.2/Source/Library/MoreAuthSample/MoreUNIX/
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._MoreUNIX.c.668o9B": No such file or directory
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._MoreUNIX.h.iRddoe": No such file or directory
Apple development/ethernal Folder/__MACOSX/Ethernal 1.2/Source/Library/Utils/
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._.DS_Store.Q28weF": No such file or directory
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._BPFLib.c.E9bRiY": No such file or directory
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._BPFLib.h.a8mV9m": No such file or directory
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._GetEthernetAddrSample.c.Jm1Zsk": No such file or directory
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._GetEthernetAddrSample.h.vRsMMZ": No such file or directory
Apple development/ethernal Folder/__MACOSX/Ethernal 1.2/Source/Source/
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._.DS_Store.Xhfs5P": No such file or directory
Applications (Mac OS 9)/.DS_Store
       15364 100%  100.70kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#3929, to-check=840194/844693)
```

and this:

```
Archive/xxx/Downloads/Applications/File tools/FileSalvage.dmg Folder/__MACOSX/
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._FileSalvage.dmg.mRiI07": No such file or directory
```

and this:

```
other files/Users-old/xxx/Downloads/Applications/File tools/FileSalvage.dmg Folder/__MACOSX/
send_files failed to open "/tmp/.._FileSalvage.dmg.b68sLq": No such file or directory
```

So, my question is, why have these files failed to copy, and secondarily, why is it even using /tmp/ ? (I am using rsync 2.6.9 on Mac OS X 10.7.5)

There is no problem with permissions, because I ran the copy with 'sudo', and actually I also tried both with and without permissions on the mounted partition. At first I thought it might be interference from a cron job that was cleaning directories while I was running the copy overnight. I tried the copy again:

```
> time sudo rsync -aE --inplace  /Volumes/Files/ /Volumes/xxxx\ archive
```

and the copy failed on exactly the same 31 files (with or without the '--inplace').

I have tried looking at a couple of the files on the source partition, and although 'more' said they might be binary, it had no difficulty in outputting them to the screen. The destination copy is a bit larger than the source; I don't think this is due to compression in the source, because the files in the source were all written under Mac OS X 10.5.8 or earlier which I think is before compression because available. I think the size difference may be due to spotlight writing to the disk?

The failure is not reported on reading the original file, but on reading a /tmp file, but the default is to stage the copy into the destination, not onto /tmp, so it should not be using /tmp at all.

The failure is completely reproducible, so any ideas what is wrong, or how to diagnose the problem?